# sort array of objects with letters and numbers in descending order

Tags: javascript

```
data = [{"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.9"}, 
        {"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.10"}, 
        {"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.1"}]
```

I want to sort this data in descending order alphabetically and numerically both.

I tried the below but it doesn't work on array of objects.

```
var myArray  = data;
var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
console.log(myArray.sort(collator.compare));
```

How should I go about it, the data of objects is received and it should be returned as objects only and not as array to display.

Comment: Can you post the expected result?

Comment: no change returns same sorting order with undefined

Comment: No, what do you expect as a valid output?

Comment: data = ["PHX7260.AE5020003.1", 
         "PHX7260.AE5020003.9", 
        "PHX7260.AE5020003.10"]

Comment: the above in descending order , means reverse

Comment: What is `new Intl.Collator` ??

Comment: also since PHX7260.AE5020003 are same hence the output expected is above , if the string aredifferent it should sort the string first and then the number

Comment: @JonasW. google it

Comment: @frodo2975 - it is not , there they are doing it only by last name that is only string , here it is both

Comment: It is the same thing, you're sorting an array of objects by a property of each object. Pretty much you just need to run it through a .map call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#sort` with `string#localeCompare` with `numeric` property set to `true`.

```js
const data = [{"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.9"}, {"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.10"},{"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.1"}];
data.sort((a,b) => b.map_name.localeCompare(a.map_name, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do this. I always forget that `localeCompare` is a thing, very nice.

Comment: This approach is not sorting according to the OP's statement.  Even doesn't follow this *also since PHX7260.AE5020003 are same hence the output expected is above , if the string aredifferent it should sort the string first and then the number*

Comment: Thanks @Ele. Updated the solution.

Comment: breaks at error: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined

Comment: It means that one of the objects doesn't have `map_name` property.

Answer (score 0):

- You can get the string and the number before/after the last dot respectively.
- Compare the string first, if they are equal sort by number else use the function `localeCompare`.

*This approach sorts using descending direction.*

Look how `ZHX7260.AE5020003.10` is placed at the first position.

```js
var data = [{"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.9"},        {"map_name": "ZHX7260.AE5020003.10"},        {"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.10"},        {"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.1"}];
        
data.sort((a, b) => {
  var astr = a.map_name.substring(0, a.map_name.lastIndexOf('.'));
  var bstr = b.map_name.substring(0, b.map_name.lastIndexOf('.'));
  
  if (astr === bstr) {
    var aidx = a.map_name.substring(a.map_name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var bidx = b.map_name.substring(b.map_name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    
    return bidx - aidx;
  } else return bstr.localeCompare(astr);
}); 

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
also since PHX7260.AE5020003 are same hence the output expected is above , if the string aredifferent it should sort the string first and then the number
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript's native `Array.sort()` method, you can split your strings on `.` and do a multi-step sort like below:

```js
var data = [{"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.9"}, 
        {"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.10"}, 
        {"map_name": "PHX7260.AE5020003.1"}]
    
function compare(a,b){
  if(!!parseInt(a) && !!parseInt(b)){
    a = parseInt(a)
    b = parseInt(b)
  }
  if(a > b) return 1
  else if(a < b) return -1
  else return 0
}
    
function sortData(a,b){
  let a_arr = a.map_name.split('.'),
    b_arr = b.map_name.split('.')
    
  while(a_arr.length){
    let val = compare(a_arr.shift(), b_arr.shift())
    if(val) return val
  }
  
  return 0
}

console.log(data.sort(sortData))
```